# creating a json output in php

Tags: php, json

This is what i would like to end up with

```
{
  name: 'creditor',
  y: 5600
}, {
  name: 'Supplier',
  y: 2400,
}, {
  name: 'Normal',
  y: 1038
}, {
  name: 'Suppliers',
  y: 4377
},
```

I have tied:

```
  $roles = AllUserRoles::find()->all();

  $userdata = [];
  foreach ($roles as $role) {
     $name = array('name' => $role["description"]);
     $trucks = TblTrucks::find()->where(['role_id'=>$role["id"]])->count();
     $totals = array('y'=>$trucks);
     array_push($userdata, array($name => $totals));

  }

  return json_encode($userdata);
```

But now am getting an illegal string offset at array_push

How can i generate json as above from php?

Comment: Why did you decide on `array_push`? A simple append `$list[] = [...]` would have been easier, and avoided $name being an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it like below:-

```
$roles = AllUserRoles::find()->all();

$userdata = [];
foreach ($roles as $role) {
    $name = $role["description"];
    $trucks = TblTrucks::find()->where(['role_id'=>$role["id"]])->count();
    $userdata[] = ['name'=>$name,'y'=> $trucks]; // assign data directly

}
return json_encode($userdata);
```

Comment: `'y'=> $trucks`

Comment: @AbraCadaver  i am in the process of editing that. thanks for telling BTW

Comment: ok i cant mark before 7 mins are over but will surely mark it.